CodeRunner extension Visual Studio: Not showing in Output
Trying to get Script output to show in output tab using code runner extension. Was previously working but tinkered around to see if I could trouble shoot a script in terminal. Now unable to revert.
JSON Settings for Visual Studio Setup:
{
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Dark",
  "workbench.startupEditor": "none",
  "debug.console.fontSize": 24,
  "markdown.preview.fontSize": 24,
  "scm.inputFontSize": 24,
  "editor.fontSize": 24,
  "terminal.integrated.fontSize": 12,
  "editor.mouseWheelZoom": true,
  "workbench.settings.openDefaultSettings": true,
  "telemetry.enableTelemetry": false,
  "telemetry.enableCrashReporter": false,
  "editor.accessibilitySupport": "off",

  // CODE RUNNER SETTINGS
  "code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,
  "code-runner.ignoreSelection": true,
  "code-runner.saveAllFilesBeforeRun": false,
  "code-runner.saveFileBeforeRun": true,
  "code-runner.showExecutionMessage": false,
  "code-runner.executorMap": {
    "python": "python3 -u"
  }
}

Code Runner Extension has been reinstalled a number of times however I am unable to get the output of the script to run in the output tab. Instead it is showing in Terminal despite specifying to not do this.

One thing I have noticed is that changes dont seem to be taking affect without restarting visual studio...
However even on restart with this issue nothing changes.

Hardly a solution (more like turn it on and off again) and most likely overkill but here's what I did:
  rm -rf ~/.vscode*
  rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Code
  rm -rf ~/Library/Saved\ Application\ State/com.microsoft.VSCode.savedState
  rm -rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.microsoft.VSCode.helper.plist 
  rm -rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.microsoft.VSCode.plist 
  rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.microsoft.VSCode
  rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.microsoft.VSCode.ShipIt
  sudo rm -rf /Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app

Reinstalled VScode and Code Runner.
The instead of messing with JSON directly. Just used default checkboxes

JSON output of this:
Note you may wish to change python to:
  "python": "$pythonPath -u $fullFileName",

to enable automatic selection
{
    "code-runner.executorMap": {

        "javascript": "node",
        "java": "cd $dir && javac $fileName && java $fileNameWithoutExt",
        "c": "cd $dir && gcc $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "zig": "zig run",
        "cpp": "cd $dir && g++ $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "objective-c": "cd $dir && gcc -framework Cocoa $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "php": "php",
        "python": "python3 -u",
        "perl": "perl",
        "perl6": "perl6",
        "ruby": "ruby",
        "go": "go run",
        "lua": "lua",
        "groovy": "groovy",
        "powershell": "powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File",
        "bat": "cmd /c",
        "shellscript": "bash",
        "fsharp": "fsi",
        "csharp": "scriptcs",
        "vbscript": "cscript //Nologo",
        "typescript": "ts-node",
        "coffeescript": "coffee",
        "scala": "scala",
        "swift": "swift",
        "julia": "julia",
        "crystal": "crystal",
        "ocaml": "ocaml",
        "r": "Rscript",
        "applescript": "osascript",
        "clojure": "lein exec",
        "haxe": "haxe --cwd $dirWithoutTrailingSlash --run $fileNameWithoutExt",
        "rust": "cd $dir && rustc $fileName && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "racket": "racket",
        "scheme": "csi -script",
        "ahk": "autohotkey",
        "autoit": "autoit3",
        "dart": "dart",
        "pascal": "cd $dir && fpc $fileName && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "d": "cd $dir && dmd $fileName && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "haskell": "runghc",
        "nim": "nim compile --verbosity:0 --hints:off --run",
        "lisp": "sbcl --script",
        "kit": "kitc --run",
        "v": "v run",
        "sass": "sass --style expanded",
        "scss": "scss --style expanded",
        "less": "cd $dir && lessc $fileName $fileNameWithoutExt.css",
        "FortranFreeForm": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "fortran-modern": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "fortran_fixed-form": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "fortran": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "sml": "cd $dir && sml $fileName",
        "mojo": "mojo run",
        "erlang": "escript",
        "spwn": "spwn build",
        "pkl": "cd $dir && pkl eval -f yaml $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt.yaml",
        "gleam": "gleam run -m $fileNameWithoutExt"
    },
    "code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,
    "code-runner.showExecutionMessage": false,
    "code-runner.saveFileBeforeRun": true
}

